# Write text with some fixed amount of space from the margin

Tags: indentation

How would I write the following in LaTeX:

```
_Abstract_  
XXXX This is the  
XXXX abstract.

_Keywords_  
XXXX keyword1, keyword1
```

In the above the letter `X` stands for space.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using the `adjustwidth` environment from the [`changepage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage) it is possible to push the left/right margins of the text in by any given amount. The environment has the following syntax:

```
\begin{adjustwidth}{<leftskip>}{<rightskip>}
  ...
\end{adjustwidth}
```

where it pushes the left margin in by `<leftskip>` and the right margin in by `<rightskip>`. To make the indentation align between the **Abstract** and **Keywords**, use the same `<leftskip>` length in `\hspace{<leftskip>}`.

Here is a minimal working example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\section*{Abstract}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{1cm}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{adjustwidth}
\section*{Keywords}
\hspace{1cm} keyword1, keyword2

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{document}
```

The **Abstract** and **Keyword** titles were typeset as `\section*`, although this can be changed. For example, the [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) document class provides an `abstract` environment which typesets a heading and indents the abstract (like the `adjustwidth` environment) `\leftmargin` from the left and right. As such, you could use `\hspace{\leftmargin}` to have the **Keywords** indent the same distance. For completeness, in order to obtain the same formatting then, you could use

```
% <other content and document preamble>
\begin{abstract}
  % <your abstract goes here>
\end{abstract}
\textbf{Keywords} \par
\hspace{\leftmargin} keyword1, keyword2, ...
% <article content>
```

Finally, [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) was merely used for dummy text.

Answer (score 7):

For the KOMA classes there is the `addmargin` environment which is similar to `adjustwidth`. It has the syntax

```
\begin{addmargin}[<left indentation>]{<indentation>}
 contents
\end{addmargin}
```

By only supplying the mandatory argument, the same indentation will occur on both left and right side, while the optional argument will overwrite that for the left side.

There is also a starred version of the environment, for twosided layouts, where the optional argument sets the inner indent.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{addmargin}[2cm]{0cm}
\lipsum[2]
\end{addmargin}
\begin{addmargin}{2cm}
\lipsum[3]
\end{addmargin}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 1):

Try `\phantom{XXXX}` which will leave the same space as `XXXX` would have occupied. There are also `\hphantom{XXXX}` and `\vphantom{XXXX}` to leave only horizonal or vertical space taking zero space in the other dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you can find a document class that supports abstract.

Or you could try `\hspace{5cm}` or `\hskip{5cm}`, I forget.