# How can I indent a block of text for a specified amount?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, quoting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Indenting a whole paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph)
>   [Write text with some fixed amount of space from the margin](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36121/write-text-with-some-fixed-amount-of-space-from-the-margin)

I would like to indent a paragraph or two for a specific amount.

The `quote` environment is not suitable, since indentation width is not configurable.

[An article](http://timmurphy.org/2009/08/15/indenting-a-block-of-text-in-latex/) suggested using `{\addtolength{\leftskip}{5mm} text}`, but that doesn't work for me.

[Another article](http://claus.castelodelego.org/archives/116) suggested a very hacky way, which involved temporarily modifying global margins.

Is there a clean solution for this?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36121/write-text-with-some-fixed-amount-of-space-from-the-margin/ or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph/

Comment: Could you elaborate on "doesn't work for me" what did you try exactly and why didn't it work?

Comment: did you try this with `\par` at the end before closing the group in which the `\leftskip` is adjusted?

Comment: @Seamus I tried the exact command quoted, and it didn't affect `text` layout.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You may use `addmargin` environment of either a [KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) class or the KOMA-Script package `scrextend`. Here an example with a standard class and package `scrextend`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for demo only!
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{addmargin}[1em]{2em}% 1em left, 2em right
\lipsum[2]
\end{addmargin}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Results in:

[image]

Comment: A tip for other sloppy readers: the package is `s c r extend`, not `s r c extend`.

Comment: An alternative is `\begin{adjustwidth}{1em}{1em} CONTENT \end{adjustwidth}` with `\usepackage{changepage}`. This worked better in my case because `scrextend` raised a warning that I could not get rid of using the `silence` package. The warning was `Command \@footnotemark has changed. Check if current package is valid.`

Comment: @CarlosPinzón This warning does not occur with my example. Maybe you are not using an up-to-date version of `scrextend`.

Comment: @ntc2 I wrote `scrextend` not `srcextend`. So I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @Schweinebacke, regarding the scr/src comment, he's just warning the readers that the package name is weird, so it is easy to misread scr as src. Your answer is fine, is just to help users notice that (programmers use src very often as short for "source"). Regarding my comment, I'm working with a larger document and I got that issue. I'm just adding that if someone gets stuck in the same place, my comment might help them. We are both just complementing your answer.