# Compile Error: KOMA-script (scrextend) 'Command \setfootnoterule already defined'; Package clash?

Tags: indentation, memoir, koma-script, incompatibility

I followed the instruction to [indent a block of text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37080/how-can-i-indent-a-block-of-text-for-a-specified-amount) in my document. So I added new package **scrextend** and simple code:

```
\begin{addmargin}[1em]
indented text text text
\end{addmargin}
```

but when I compile I get following error:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/koma-script/scrextend.sty:1206:
LaTeX Error: Command \setfootnoterule already defined.
           Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
```

I don't have a definition of *\setfootnoterule* anywhere, so I assume it comes from one of the other packages I'm using, which I tried to comment one by one, but it didn't help...

Can somebody please point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%class file
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{memoir}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%default package
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsfonts}
\usepackage{times,mathptmx,bm,amsmath}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
% mine
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% package for strikethrough (\st{})
\usepackage{soul}
% package for adding margin to block of text
%\begin{addmargin}[1em]{2em}% 1em left, 2em right
%\lipsum[1]
%\end{addmargin}
\usepackage{scrextend}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection.\arabic{equation}}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\def\citeasnoun{\cite}

\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\scriptsize}

% modify listing property
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\tiny
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

\begin{addmargin}[1em]{2em}
indented text text text
\end{addmargin}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this package. It is a mix of various KOMA-definitions but it doesn't really make a effort to keep compability with other classes. With the standard classes it can work quite ok but with a class like memoir the probability of clashes is high.

Comment: You should try one the first two answers to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35933/5872 (from which the question you mention is a duplicate) to achieve the desired effect without needing `scrextend`

Comment: BTW, `amssymb` loads `amsfonts`, and `latexsym` is thus superfluous.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanation and words of advice. I assumed a clash between packages, I didn't suspect that class has anything to do with it : ). 
I changed indenting using [changepage package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35934/84760). I will play with KOMA some other time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `\setfootnoterule` is defined both by the class `memoir` and the package `scrextend`. Changing the class e.g. to `scrbook` seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I didn't use this answer, but you clarified what I'm doing wrong so I used [different approach for indentation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph/35934#35934) keeping _memoir_ class.

Answer (score 0):

not sure, but to my knowledge Koma-Script ("A bundle of versatile classes and packages") is meant to be used as a bundled suite, meaning you should also use a koma-document-class (instead of memoir) and also probably not the geometry package, see scrguide for further information. (maybe including scrbase would suffice, but you either want to use koma or you do not want to)

if you are only interested in indenting a paragraph, look at the duplicate questions of the one you linked to for example [Indenting a whole paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35933/indenting-a-whole-paragraph) for a solution outside the koma world

Comment: The first paragraph of your answer is incorrect (except for the part about the `geometry` package): The `scrextend` package is meant to be used with non-KOMA-Script classes, especially the standard classes, and does provide features which could be separated from the KOMA-Script classes.

Comment: Thanks @Bort. I decided not to change to KOMA world, so I've followed another answer on how to indent using [changepage package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35934/84760).