# Set width of text (included from external file) only - keep rest of page as is

Tags: margins, include

## What I want

I have a document that includes text from several external `.tex` files. These files can contain `\section{}` commands or `\begin{quote}` environments. Furthermore, I use the `lineno` package to number the lines of the includes files. To allow writing notes to the printing documents, I would like to limit the width of the included text. This width, however, should only affect the included text and not other parts of the document.

### Code example

Basically, my code should look like this:

```
\chapter{Entry number 10}
Text text text text text text text text text text text text text

% HELP ME: command to set text width

\linenumbers
\input{external.tex}
\nolinenumbers

% HELP ME: command to reset text width
```

### How the result should look like

```
ENTRY NUMBER 10
===============

Text text text text text text text text text text text text text

1. Included part 10-a
---------------------

2. Text of the included part that has
3. a smaller text width that even works
4. when quotations or other subsections
5. are used.

6. Note the line numbers.
```

## Minimal Example

Here is an example to demonstrate what I want and what does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% imagine this part is included from a file %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% show line numbers
\linenumbers

% HELPME: something that does not correctly work
\par\begingroup\rightskip12em

% a paragraph with correct margin
\section{This is an example for a very long subtitle}
\lipsum[1]

% margin is ignored for quoted text
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}

% margin is ignored for item lists
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize} 

\par\endgroup

% no line numbers beyond this
\nolinenumbers
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Note that text in the `quote` environment and the list does not have a correct margin.

## What I tried

- `minipage`: Works perfectly, but does not work if the included document is longer than one page. A `minipage` environment that floats over many pages would help
- `\newgeometry{}` command of the `geometry` package: Works perfectly, but always begins a whole new page. I, however, want the change to only affect the included part and not the surrounding text.
- Using `adjustwidth` environment from the `changepage` package: This does not work when the text in the environment contains `\section{}` commands.
- Using an environment and change its width: Had several issues... For instance, the margin was ignored as soon as the included text contained a `quote`. Other environment could not cope with `\section{}` commands in the included text.

## Another problem

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Text1}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{2cm}

\section{Text2}

Text3

\begin{quote}
Text4
\end{quote}

\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

The reason why I did not use `adjustwidth` before was that the above example has a compilation error: "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." in the line of `\begin{quote}`. The error disappears when I remove either of

- the line `\chapter{Text1}`
- the line `\section{Text2}`
- the line `Text3`
- the `adjustwidth` environment

How can this be?

**Edit**: I asked a new question ([Strange compilation problem using adjustwidth environment from changepage package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60992/strange-compilation-problem-using-adjustwidth-environment-from-changepage-packag)) and close this one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write text with some fixed amount of space from the margin](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36121/write-text-with-some-fixed-amount-of-space-from-the-margin)

Comment: Unfortunately not: The adjustwidth environment does not seem to work if commands like \section are used.

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I added an example. I hope this demonstrates what I want.

Comment: I put the compilation error into a new question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60992/strange-compilation-problem-using-adjustwidth-environment-from-changepage-packag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As linked in the comments the environment works as expected

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{changepage}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{2cm}
\linenumbers
\section{This is an example for a very long subtitle}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{quote}
\lipsum[1]
\end{quote}
\begin{itemize}
\item \lipsum[1]
\end{itemize} 
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Marco, Thanks a lot! The example works. It does, however, not work in my setting. I describe the problem above. It would be so cool if you had another look at this.

Comment: I explained the problem arising with `adjustwidth` above under "Another problem". It brings me a strange compilation error.