# Strange compilation problem using adjustwidth environment from changepage package

Tags: errors, packages, compiling

The following code gives a compilation error.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Text1}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{2cm}

\section{Text2}

Text3

\begin{quote}
Text4
\end{quote}

\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```

The error says: "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item." in the line of `\begin{quote}`. The error disappears when I remove either of

- the line `\chapter{Text1}`
- the line `\section{Text2}`
- the line `Text3`
- the `adjustwidth` environment

How can this be?

Comment: Add `\leavevemode` before you set the `section`: `\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{2cm}
\leavevmode`

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, it introduces a blank line. Do you know how this can be avoided? Negative `\vspace` would not work, because I want to number the lines.

Answer (score 4):

The nesting fails. I don't know why but the following works:

The relevant part is:

```
\nointerlineskip\leavevmode
```

It's the classic 'a lot of stuff is implemented by LaTeX as a trivlist, even though this results in weird error messages' business. As a result, you need something to deal with the `\par` tokens correctly, which `\leavevmode` does.
Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Text1}

\begin{adjustwidth}{1cm}{2cm}
\nointerlineskip\leavevmode
\section{Text2}

Text3

\begin{quote}
Text4
\end{quote}

\end{adjustwidth}

\end{document}
```