# Align the text in a simple way

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I wonder if you have a more practical way of doing the following:

- Indent the text in 4cm
- Maintaining justified alignment
- The text should occupy all available space except the edges and 4cm

Something like the image below (the right alignment is bad)
[image]

It is possible to do this also using two minipage, but it is still not very practical

Comment: So you want specific paragraphs to be centre justified with 4cm indent not your whole document, right?

Comment: See if http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35933/586  or http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36121/586 help.

Comment: Yes, the option to create a `\newenvironment` In one of the answer is perfect. Because I do not know English, I find it difficult to search. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Why do you need two minipages? See my answer using only one.

Comment: Using two minipages was one way to do it, but I'd like something more practical. Creating an environment from your answer is just what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-4cm}
    \lipsum[1]
    \xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}
\end{minipage}

\prevdepth\tpd\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: results]

Why do you need that?

Comment: Brazilian standards require that long quotations be made in this way.

Comment: @MarceloRodrigues You should watch out for the incorrect spacing between the minipage-paragraph and the next one. I added `\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}` and `\prevdepth\tpd` for that (taken from one of the answers to the duplicate posts).